# Stuck on checking for leap year and a valid date

Tags: matlab, validation, date, leap-year

I wrote this code to check for date validation, but I am stuck on how to check for leap year.

```
date = '01/02/1990';
display('hello')
a=strsplit(date,'/');
day = a(1);
display(day);

%b=strsplit('/',date,'/');
month = a(2);
display(month);

%c=strsplit('/','/',date);
year = a(3);
display(year);

if (month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12)
    if (day>=1&&day<=31)

        display(' Its a valid date')
    else
        display(' Its NOT a valid date')
    end
end
```

How do I incorporate leap year calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @gregswiss for pointing out my error in leap year calculation. This directly incorporates the check into the code, thus you do not have to include an a priori list of leap years:

```
if (mod(year,4) == 0 && mod(year,100) ~= 0) || mod(year,400) == 0
     disp('Leap year'); 
else
     disp('Non-leap year'); 
end
```

Just include this in your `if` statement the same way you check your months. Then if your year has a corresponding entry in `LeapYear` it is a leap year:

```
if sum(year==LeapYear)
    disp('This is a leap year')
end
```

The reason for the sum is that `year==LeapYear` will be a logical array containing 30 values, of which 29 zero and 1 one if your `year` is indeed a leap year, or it will contain 30 zeros.
I recently found out about a more obscure function: [`eomday`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/leapyear.html) which tells you the last day of the month, so a simple `eomday(year,month)==29` is sufficient to tell you whether it is a leap year. (There's [`leapyear`][2] as well, but that's in the aerospace toolbox)

```
    date = input('Please enter a date in the DD/MM/YYYY format ','s')
    display('hello')
    tmp=strsplit(date,'/');
    a(1) = str2num(tmp{1}); % Create an array out of your string
    a(2) = str2num(tmp{2});
    a(3) = str2num(tmp{3});
    day = a(1);
    display(day);

     month = a(2);
     display(month);

    year = a(3);
    display(year);
    if eomday(year,month)==29
         disp('Leap year'); 
    else
         disp('Non-leap year'); 
    end
    %if (mod(year,4) == 0 & mod(year,100) ~= 0) | mod(year,400) == 0
    %     disp('Leap year'); 
    %else
    %     disp('Non-leap year'); 
    %end
      if (month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12)
       if (day>=1&&day<=31)

         display(' It is a valid date')
   else
         display(' It is NOT a valid date')
           end
       end
```

Comment: I am very new to matlab do you mind editing the code for me please.

Comment: and will it check for years > 2016 ?

Comment: Well, no, but you can expand that to an arbitrary date. You can set it between -2000 and +6000 if you want. I'll add how to remove the millenia that way

Comment: Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in leapyear (line 16)
       if sum(year==LeapYear)

Comment: Could be you need `a(1) = str2num(tmp(1));` i.e. round braces instead of curlies, but I cant check since my matlab doesnt have `strplit` yet

Comment: Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in leapyear (line 6)
    a(1) = str2num(tmp{1}); % Create an array out of your string

Comment: I cant do anything here if all you do is post errors. I cant recreate the problem, since, as I stated before, the function `strsplit` is not yet available in my version. I suggest you check the datatype of `a`, which you obtain with the `strplit`, then find out how to convert that to a numeric array. `str2num` makes numbers from strings, `cell2mat` makes matrices out of cells.

Comment: @Santosh - I tested the code and it runs fine.  You are most likely **not** putting in the input properly.  Make sure `input` has a `'s'` flag to denote that the input is a string.

Comment: @rayryeng how do make sure it has 's' flag ?

Comment: @Santosh - By copying and pasting the above code **exactly** into a file and run it.

Comment: @rayryeng are you sure you are able to run it successfully I am still getting that error "Conversion to cell from double is not
possible."

Comment: @rayryeng or if you could provide equivalent program for this that would be helpful Thanks

Comment: have you entered the day as **DD/MM/YYYY**? When you run this, a text message appears and you have to input the date *exactly*  in that form. And yes, it runs for @rayryeng just checked it myself

Comment: @Adriaan Yes I provide valid input in the required format but still getting that error . Thank you all for your help so far I need this for assignment.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing wrong, the code is fine. If this is an assignment it might be best if you try writing your own code, since a course is there to learn you something, not to make others do your homework

Comment: @Santosh, did you even include the slashes in the format? And did you susbtitute each letter for a corresponding number? You know, like literally entering "01/01/1970".

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes I did exactly what is required :(

Comment: Since you are the only one having this issue and no-one can replicate it, I am leaving this thread as finished and correct.

Comment: @Adriaan What proof should I provide so that you believe me attached is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr2sylak3u0q6lo/error.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @rayryeng File Version : 1.0.0.1 Product Version 8.5.0.184244

Comment: No. That's not what I meant. R2013A? R2014A? which one?

Comment: @rayryeng it's R2015a

Comment: @Adriaan  that error is resolved using  a{1} = str2double(tmp{1}); but got new one Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Comment: computing all leaps years and then testing if it's a leap year is not really necessary, why not test if the particular year is leap directly - especially since you have no idea what year the user may be testing a priori? additionally 2000 IS a leap year, 1900 is NOT.

Comment: @gregswiss thanks, I updated the code. My mistake, I thought millennia were and centuries werent, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Gregorian calendar rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) the correct test for leap year is:

```
if (mod(year,4) == 0 & mod(year,100) ~= 0) | mod(year,400) == 0
     disp('Leap year'); 
else
     disp('Non-leap year'); 
end
```

You may considering wrapping the test in a function 'isLeap' or something similar...

Comment: Good test. Considering the OP wanted me to write his full code I've included it in my answer and everything works fine now, thanks.

Comment: You can use  `&&` and `||` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be made more robust and simpler using the `datetime` function which will handle the parsing and throw an error if the date is not valid

```
date = '01/02/1990';
try
   d = datetime(date, 'InputFormat', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
   % access day, month, year using: d.Day, d.Month and d.Year...
   % ...
   disp(' Its a valid date')
catch 
   disp(' Its NOT a valid date')
end
```